# asp:ImageButton doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with the ASP.NET ImageButton control.

What I would like is: when I click on the image I will be redirect to the login page of Google, Facebook or Twitter, but this doesn't happen. This is my code for the Login page:

```
<section id="socialLoginForm">
    <h2>Use another service to log in.</h2>
    <uc:OpenAuthProviders runat="server" ID="OpenAuthLogin" />
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="providerDetails" ItemType="Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.ProviderDetails"
         SelectMethod="GetProviderNames" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:ImageButton ID="Login"  runat="server" Width="40" Height="40" ImageUrl='<%# Item.ExtraData["Icon"] %>' AlternateText="Log in using your <%#: Item.ProviderDisplayName %> account." />

         </ItemTemplate>
         <EmptyDataTemplate>
             <p>There are no external authentication services configured. </p>
         </EmptyDataTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>
</section>
```

this is the code behind:

```
 public partial class Login : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx";
        OpenAuthLogin.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

        var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
        }
    }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProviderDetails> GetProviderNames()
    {
        return OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.GetAll();
    }
```

Comment: can you please write What happens ? (and from where you get this example ?)

Comment: What does your code-behind do on clicked? When you say it doesn't happen, what does happen?!

Comment: I get the example here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/24/customizing-the-login-ui-when-using-oauth-openid.aspx

Comment: The problem is that when I click on the image I am redirect to my login page

Answer (score 0):

you can add List view "OnItemCommand" command 
Aspx page

```
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="providerDetails" ItemType="Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.ProviderDetails"
        SelectMethod="GetProviderNames" ViewStateMode="Disabled" OnItemCommand="ListView_OnItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="Login" runat="server" Width="40" Height="40" ImageUrl='<%# Item.ExtraData["Icon"] %>'
                AlternateText="Log in using your <%#: Item.ProviderDisplayName %> account." CommandName="Login" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <p>
                There are no external authentication services configured.
            </p>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void ListView_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "Login"))
    {
     // do what ever you want
    }
  }
```

Source :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx